# Timezones on New Year in Space Pilot 3000

Tags: futurama, time

During re-watching the *Space Pilot 3000* I've noticed:

1. People in various countries are counting at the same time despite that there should be several time zones.
2. When the earth is shown from space USA was in daylight.

Given that the show usually breaks physics on purpose was there a reason to do it (say joke) or is it just an error/within *licentia poetica*?

Comment: To quote MST3K:  Remember it's just a show, and just relax ;-)

Comment: @SteveED: 'Just repeat to yourself "It's just a show,
I should really just relax"' is the correct quote. :P

Comment: The problem is that it might be quite funny cultural reference which I might not get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you watch the commentary for the episode, they bring up your first point. The reason they did it was that it was funny and created a nice contrast when they repeated it later in the episode. They knew it was wrong, but also that most people wouldn't think about it in the moment on first watch.

Answer (score -2):

Since Earth basically becomes one big country wouldn't they all use the same time zone.

Comment: Time zones depend on physical location of regions, not their political affiliation. There are *today* several countries that have more than one time zone, because they span a large area above the earth's surface.

Comment: @bitmask: Not quite true - time zones are usually adjust to have administrative regions in one timezone to make it more convenient (or even to larger areas like CET which covers most of the Europe) so 'politics' do play some role. That said there exists countries which have many times (say US, Canada, Russia, China...)